# "Unwind" from ANY view controller back to the storyboard's initial view controller

Tags: swift, storyboard

Pre-conditions (Swift):

1. I have an app with many view controllers on a single storyboard.
2. There is a navigation controller, but the first few view controllers are not in it.  (I point this out b/c I can't just "pop to root" here.)
3. There is a "session expire" event that triggers after x minutes.

Use case:

Regardless of which screen the user is on, if I see the "session expired" notification, I want to send the user back to my storyboard's initial view controller.

My question:

How exactly can I accomplish that without manually creating an unwind segue on every single view controller?  Is there some way to "throw away" the current instance of the storyboard and start over at the beginning?

(I'm not worried about remembering their current state and what not...it doesn't matter for this scenario.  It expired, they lose, they start over.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could "grab" the relevant viewController from its storyboard identifier - as Pawan Araballi said in his answer - and set the `window.rootViewController` property on your `AppDelegate`.
I think this approach is better than presenting the viewController on top of the UI you already have.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this would be to navigate to the viewcontroller by using storyboard id.

click on the *main.storyboard* and click on the viewcontroller. On the identity inspector enable the storyboard **Use Storyboard ID** and give an ID to it.

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc : UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainNavigationStoryBoard") as! UINavigationController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Just use the above code to navigate to the specific viewcontroller after the sesssion is expired